# Appending TCM of newly created component to component title

Tags: 2013, event-system

I'm trying to write an event that will basically append the TCM value to the end of the component name

```
this-is-my-componentname-1235
```

While for existing components this is easy enough during 'OnComponentSavePre', I've run into a roadblock for new components, as from what I can tell I can't obtain the Id until the 'TransactionCommitted' phase, at which point I can't impact the current component.

Is there any way for me to either obtain the Id prior to the 'TransactionCommitted' Phase, or a way for me to post commit go back and update the component title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the transaction committed phase you would have to call the Save method on the component, which would create a new major version. Unfortunately, this is the only way to do it as far as I know.

Comment: New items don't have an id until they're saved, so yeah, no easy way to do this on V1

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, you need to save the item for it to get an Id. This means that somehow you will need to enforce a second write.

I don't see why you couldn't do this in the Transaction Committed phase. The component is saved, so you can read it anew, modify it and save it.

The only other possibility I can think of is workflow.